# creating an array of structures and making them as linked lists and traversing them using c

Tags: c

In this program I created a array(`node[3]`) of structure(`struct eg`) and made them as linked lists while trying to print the elements of the list I am getting only 1 output that is 3

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct eg
{
    struct eg *next;
    int age;
}node[3];

main()
{
    struct eg *head,*temp;
    int i;

    head=temp=node;
    for(i=1;i<3;i++)
    {
       temp->age=i;
       temp->next=temp+i;
    }
    temp->next=0;
    temp->age=3;
    while(head!=0)
    {
       printf("%d",head->age);
       head=head->next;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and review your post.

Comment: @HopefulLlama I think the code in the question is pretty much MCVE.

Comment: Okay, my bad. Must just be me then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp->next=temp++;
```

You're reading and modifying `temp` in a single expression with no sequence point.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to separate the increment from the assignment:

```
temp->next=temp+1;
temp++;
```

Comment: You could even move the `temp++` into the increment part of the `for` to make it clear that it is incremented for each loop (i.e. `for(i=1;i<3;i++,temp++)`)